# How Can I send json file by ajax to django?

Tags: python, jquery, json, django, ajax

Can I send .json with data like (login,password from input html) to django who download this file and check login/password? Then I want return results by django to js,jquery. I dont wan use forms-django in form-html and dont want change urls.

code html:

```
<form id='login_form' action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div id='Login_form'>
    <p>Login: </p> <input type="text" onblur="CheckEmptyElements();" id="flogin">
    <p>Password: </p> <input type="password" onblur="CheckEmptyElements();" id="lpass">
    <div id="butt_form">
    <button type="button" class="butt_forme" id="button" onclick="CheckBeforeSend();">Enter</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

code js:

```
 var LoginInput = document.getElementById('flogin');
  if(LoginInput.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+['.']+[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+$/) == null)
  {
    if(document.getElementById('Windows').childElementCount > 2)
    {
      document.getElementById('Windows').children[0].remove();
    }
    AddPicture("paperJsConn");
  } 
  else // <--- Check login/pass in base django
  {
    document.getElementById("button").type = "submit";
    $.ajax({                                                                                                                           
      type:"POST",                                                                                                                    
      url: '',                                                                                                   
      data: {
        "login": 
        "password":
      },                                                                                  
      success: function(response){ 
        //animation and change site if correct login/pass or reloaded site.

       }                                                                                                                             
  });
  }
```

and views.py:

```
def Logget(request):
if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
    //take login from json and check in base by loop
    //if find check password
    if: // correct
        // return .json or message that is correct.
    else:
      // return .json or message that is not correct.
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Someone help please?